# Synchronization at kernel level during insmod

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, driver

I am a kernel newbie, I have been working out with the semaphores lately, which help in synchronizing among the kernel threads, I know its not a good way of synchronization but please bear with me If I am missing something here.
I have two modules, In which I try to access a common function by exporting the symbol to the kernel symbol table from the first module and this will be accessed by the second module during the `init_module()` calls.

The first module as give below has the exported symbol "caller",

```
#define DEBUG                                        
#include<linux/init.h>                               
#include<linux/module.h>                             

struct semaphore sem =__SEMAPHORE_INITIALIZER(sem,1);               
EXPORT_SYMBOL(sem);


void static caller(int a, int b,int count){
        complete(&sig);
        while(1){

                int temp=20000,i;
                printk(KERN_INFO"called from module %s\n",THIS_MODULE->name);
//              down_interruptible(&sem);                                    
                while(--count>0){
                        for(i=0;i<temp;i++);
                        printk(KERN_INFO"This is a Exported Symbol into the table %d %d",a+b,count);   
                }
//              up(&sem);                                                              
                break;
        }
}
static int __init hello_kernel(void){
        int count=1000000;                                                                      
        init_completion(&sig);
        printk(KERN_ALERT"Entered In the First Module");
//      printk(KERN_INFO" Parameter passed are %d %s",arg,chrarg);
        caller(1,1,count);                                                                      
        return 0;                                                                               

}

static void __exit  hello_exit(void){
        dump_stack();
        printk(KERN_EMERG"GOHEAVEN");

}

module_init(hello_kernel);
module_exit(hello_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");                   
EXPORT_SYMBOL(caller);
module_init(hello_kernel);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

The second module calls the exported symbol "caller"

```
#define DEBUG                                        
#include<linux/init.h>                               
#include<linux/module.h>                             
void caller(int , int, int);                         


static int __init hello_kernel(void){
        int count=50;                                                           
        printk(KERN_INFO"Entered In Second Module");            
        caller(2,2,count);
        return 0;

}


static void __exit  hello_exit(void){
        dump_stack();
        printk(KERN_EMERG"GOHEAVEN");

}

module_init(hello_kernel);
module_exit(hello_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");                   
EXPORT_SYMBOL(caller);
module_init(hello_kernel);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

First module log comes first and then the Second modules init is called.

```
.........
.........
[36056.684970] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 36
[36056.685136] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 35
[36056.685301] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 34
[36056.685467] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 33
[36056.685632] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 32
[36056.685798] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 31
[36056.685963] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 30
[36056.686129] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 29
[36056.686314] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 28
[36056.686488] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 27
[36056.686664] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 26
[36056.686851] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 25
[36056.687032] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 24
[36056.687228] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 23
[36056.687393] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 22
[36056.687559] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 21
[36056.687724] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 20
[36056.687890] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 19
[36056.688055] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 18
[36056.688221] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 17
[36056.688387] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 16
[36056.688552] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 15
[36056.688718] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 14
[36056.688883] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 13
[36056.689049] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 12
[36056.689215] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 11
[36056.689380] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 10
[36056.689546] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 9
[36056.689711] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 8
[36056.689877] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 7
[36056.690044] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 6
[36056.690238] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 5
[36056.690432] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 4
[36056.690604] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 3
[36056.690786] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 2
[36056.690964] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 2 1

...........
...........
[36058.216861] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 19
[36058.216931] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 18
[36058.217001] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 17
[36058.217070] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 16
[36058.217140] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 15
[36058.217210] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 14
[36058.217279] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 13
[36058.217349] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 12
[36058.217419] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 11
[36058.217488] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 10
[36058.217558] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 9
[36058.217628] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 8
[36058.217698] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 7
[36058.217767] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 6
[36058.217837] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 5
[36058.217907] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 4
[36058.217976] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 3
[36058.218046] This is a Exported Symbol into the table 4 2
```

Without the use of the semaphore I was expecting that the dmesg kernel logs will be mixed from both the modules as they access the code inconsistently, but looks like the insmod process 
loads the modules only one after the another.

What am I missing here??

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure enough about this to write it as an answer, as I haven't looked at the details of kernel module loading for a while, but I would expect that the symbols from module 1 are not available to module 2 until module 1 has finished loading, i.e. hello_kernel() has returned.  Since count() is called there, I expect count() to complete in module 1 before module 2 can even load, and therefore no parallel calls to it.

Comment: @michaeljt I have tried exporting the symbol in just after the caller definition, also when running the insmod without taskset I am getting `Device or resource busy Error`

Comment: What I am saying is that the kernel loader will probably not accept to load module 2 depending on a symbol in module 1 until module 1's init has finished and returned.  So until module 1 has run count() to completion.  Just as an experiment, what about creating a new kernel thread in module 1's hello_kernel() and calling count() on the new thread instead of from hello_kernel()?  And does that clarify what I meant slightly?